# Android - How to scroll only image behind status bar

Tags: android

I have a CoordinatorLayout with a CollapsingToolbar and a NestedScrollView. 
The NestedScrollView has an image that scrolls up (Thats OK).
The CollapsingToolbar has a TabLayout (which contains text) and when I scroll, it appears with the status bar icons and text, and that's not OK, I want to hide the TabLayout before it gets to the status bar. Is it possible?

I have this:

[image: For better understand, I have this:]

When I scroll I get this:
[image]

But I want this:

[image]

How to scroll the content inside nestedScrollview but hide the Tabbar?

(UPDATE)
For now I have:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#505000FF"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="MY TAB"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="21sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/tmb" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \n
            TEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \n
            TEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \nTEST TEST \n"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my code I adjust margin using:

```
    private void applyTheme() {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#60000000"));
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.app_bar), (v, insets) -> {
            ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) topBar.getLayoutParams()).topMargin += insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
            ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) content.getLayoutParams()).topMargin = -((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) topBar.getLayoutParams()).height - insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
            return insets;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Updated with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below couple of attributes in your main style

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

As below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

> **UPDATE 1:**

Now to see the status bar on top of your `ImageView`,

1. Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `AppBarLayout`
2. Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` to the root view
   `CoordinatorLayout`
3. Keep the previous mentioned attributes at the style file

So, your layout would be:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#505000FF"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
....
```

This is my demo when testing

[image]

> **UPDATE 2**
>
> the behavior in your demo is different from what I need because "My
>   Tab" can be seeing from status bar, I need to cut the text when its in
>   status bar, the same as netflix does on its main activity.

You can add [`AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener?hl=ar) to the `AppBarLayout` and hide/show the `TextView` according to the offset value.

I am using arbitrary value (-10) in below demo, but you can decide another value below 0.

```
    AppBarLayout mAppBar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

    mAppBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

            if (verticalOffset <= -10) // arbitrary value
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I've already tried that, and actually I changes my status bar color to transparent,I think it's the same as this.

Comment: @user2494863 thanks for your comment.. please check updated answer

Comment: Hi Zain, the behavior in your demo is different from what I need because "My Tab" can be seeing from status bar, I need to cut the text when its in status bar, the same as netflix does on its main activity. Can you gelo me on that?

Comment: Hi @user2494863 I got it now.. please check `UPDATE 2` in the answer

Comment: Hi Zain, that's an excelent idea. I added some padding top as the verticaloffset is increased. Do you have any idea if there is any alternative to show only a part(percentage) of a view so I'll have the exatcly effect that I want here? Tks

Comment: Hi @user2494863 the problem is that the status bar is a part of *android OS window*, and we need to know when the `TextView` touches/intersects with it (TextView is part of android SDK),, Maybe you can consider 2D collision detection that will consume time and efforts, and maybe maintenance in the future wish that target your query.